# Add localStorage keys to dropdown

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Can I add the `localStorage.key(i)` to a dropdown list?

I have been trying different things in the console and can only get the JSON object by using `localStorage.key(i[0])`.

```
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){

        var str = prefix,
            lKey = localStorage.key(i);
        if (lKey.match(str)) {
            counter++;
            console.log(lKey);
           // $.each(lKey, function () {
           //   ddl.append($("<option />").val(this.);
            })
        }

    }
```

I want to be able to select the `key` to set the `key`.

Comment: Data stored in localstorage is stored as a string. If it's JSON you've saved there you probably mean to `JSON.parse` the data before you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `localStorage` API implements `key()` for retrieving keys by index and `getItem()` for retrieving items by `key`.

In your case it looks as if you want to iterate over the items in `localStorage` and print the items. You've managed to get the key, but to get the item you need to add the line:

```
localStorage.getItem(lKey);
```

To put the values you want into a dropdown option and append to your dropdown `ddl`:

```
$('<option>')
  .val(i)
  .text(lKey)
  .appendTo(ddl);
```

Comment: How could I set the `value` and `text`, it returns a list of keys which is what I want but how would I set the values?

Comment: @StudentRik Values of what? The dropdown? Or of localStorage?

Comment: If i use `console.log(i + lKey);` I get the index and the key name. I don't know how to set them as the value(i) and text(lKey) for the dropdown.

Comment: @StudentRik So what you want to do is create a dropdown with those values?

Comment: @StudentRik I appended the solution to my answer

Comment: I get cannot use in in '8' should I try and JSON.parse?